Remove the image resolution drop in the gallery in the Gutenberg backoffice
I want to remove the option to choose image resolution when creating the gallery with Gutenberg. Because when we select the gallery block and change it to large resolution, for example, not all images have this option and the gallery has different sizes (because you can assign different resolutions to each image), in my case I'm working with the height. If I remove this option I work with the css.
I already tried with theme.json, I didn't succeed, I did another test with js and it didn't work.


theme.json
"core/gallery": {
    "spacing": {
        "customMargin": false,
        "customPadding": false
    },
    "elements": {
        "image": {
            "resizeMode": false
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "sizes": false
    }
}


functions.php
wp_enqueue_script('gallery-settings', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/custom-gallery-settings.js', array(), 8, true);


wp.hooks.addFilter(
'blocks.registerBlockType',
'custom/remove-gallery-image-sizes',
(settings, name) => {
    if (name === 'core/gallery') {
        // Remove o suporte de tamanhos de imagem
        delete settings.attributes.imageSize;
    }
    return settings;
}

);

AFAIK there is no option to remove controls from the InspectorControls component in existing core blocks. The closest thing would be the editor.BlockEdit hook, but that only lets you add controls. The safest bet would be to hide the control with CSS.

functions.php
add_theme_support('editor-styles');
add_editor_style(get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/css/style-editor.css?v=1');
style-editor.css
.components-base-control.dac-e-ed-f-efac-qy3gpb.ej5x27r4{
display:none;
}
Appears in the css in